# How to set wrap for single buffer

Tags: vim

When I start up Vim, my `.vimrc` instructs the :nowrap mode. I hate the wrap while coding, as it ruins indentation and supports the coding style, where single lines get too long, too complex and less readable/concise.

However, while editing files like HTML, wrap mode is helpful, specially where there is lots of text content. It allows for faster line navigation (`gj`, `gk`...), and having long lines doesn't really matter.

So I'd like Vim set the :wrap setting based on current filetype. I tried:

```
autocmd FileType html,eruby,erb set wrap
```

However, once .html file is opened, this affects all open buffers. I would like this to affect just .html containing buffers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the help page for 'wrap', you'll see that it applies to windows instead of buffers:

```
                                        *'wrap'* *'nowrap'*
'wrap'      boolean    (default on)
            local to window
            {not in Vi}
```

This means that you have 3 options:

- Create an autocommand for `BufEnter` that reapplies `wrap` whenever you switch buffers
- Use an easy hotkey to switch between wrapping, such as: `nnoremap <F2> :set invwrap`
- Close windows like these instead of re-using them

Comment: I like option 1. How about an autocommand that executes function which checks for filetype and applies wrap command accordingly to the FileType? I will dig into VimScript...